# Oracle 10g performance between rownum or with clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am using `Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition 10.2.0.4.0 64bit`

and I would like to know, what is the best way to write the following query?

**1. With rownum**

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
  SELECT ID_DONNEE_H, DATE_DONNEE
  FROM DONNEE_H d
  WHERE d.DATE_DONNEE > sysdate -50000
  AND d.ID_SC = 38648
  ORDER BY DATE_DONNEE DESC
  )
  WHERE rownum=1;
```

**2. With a `WITH` clause**

```
with req as (
  select d.ID_DONNEE_H, row_number() over (order by DATE_DONNEE desc) as seqnum
  from DONNEE_H d
  where d.DATE_DONNEE > sysdate -50000
  AND d.ID_SC = 38648 ) 
select * from req where seqnum = 1;
```

**3. With rank clause**

```
select * from (select d.ID_DONNEE_H, row_number() over (order by DATE_DONNEE desc) as seqnum
  from DONNEE_H d
  where d.DATE_DONNEE > sysdate -50000
  AND d.ID_SC = 38648) test
  where seqnum = 1;
```

I think 2 and 3 are similar, but which is the fastest, 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: You should profile your 3 options.

Comment: I read the plan but, for another query i see that the plan show me a cost of 24 and take 40secondes, and another query that show me 4000 cost take 2secondes... i compute statistics before but nothing change, so my question is more general, the best way to use one way to another in general, i don t want to optimize this querry especialy ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can particularly generalise as to which query is the "best" in all situations. As with most IT questions, the answer is: "it depends"! You would need to investigate each query on its own merits.

As an aside, you've missed off another alternative - assuming that you're only after a single column, rather than the whole row for the highest column you're interested in:

```
with sample_data as (select 10 col1, 3 col2 from dual union all
                     select 20 col1, 3 col2 from dual union all
                     select 30 col1, 1 col2 from dual union all
                     select 40 col1, 2 col2 from dual)
select max(col1) keep (dense_rank first order by col2 desc) col1_val_of_max_col2
from   sample_data;

COL1_VAL_OF_MAX_COL2
--------------------
                  20
```

Comment: yes i understand, its just because someone tell me that order by with rownum is more expensive than a max so i just want to confirm that and understand why. and thank you for giving me a new form to write my querry :) i m going to test and verify execution plan ;)

Comment: all of the queries have got to do some sort of ordering in order to work out which one is the highest, so I don't think you can necessarily state which method is going to be the best/worst for a given situation. Things change, depending on indexes, amount of data involved, statistics, what you're querying for, etc etc.